# Conditionally average a column of data in a DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have a DataTable object, dTable, where all the DataColumn datatypes are either string  or double. Some of the numbers in a column are not present. i.e. =null. Right now I have the below code finding the average and it works well when there are values.

```
var sum = dTable.AsEnumerable().Average(x => 
{
    if (dTable.Columns[col]!=null)
    {
       return x.Field<double>(dTable.Columns[col].ColumnName); 
    }
    else
    {
        return ???;
    };

});
```

My question is what to I return when that condition is not satisfied to skip that *x*? When I encounter an empty cell in dTable it doesn't seem to know what to do.

Or if there is a totally different road I should be going down..please, by all means....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you'd like to do is to apply a `Where` clause first, to eliminate any rows that are missing data in the desired `col`:

```
var avg = dTable.AsEnumerable()
             .Where(x => x[col] != DBNull.Value)
             .Average(x => x.Field<double>(col));
```

Comment: Yes I like this but I still get this error "Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Double'. Please use a nullable type."

Comment: @Brad Whoops, forgot that your `DataRow` would have `DBNull.Value` in place of `null`. Updated my answer so that the `Where` method checks for that.

Comment: @James Haven't actually worked with a DataTable in a while (and I guess it shows.)

Answer (score 5):

Use Linq and a Where() clause so it only averages columns that fit your need:

```
// can look up based on column index or column name...  name more losely
// coupled in terms of ordering but index more efficient
var sum = dTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => x[columnIndex] != DBNull.Value)
    .Average(x => x.Field<double>(columnIndex));
```

Answer (score 2):

Can I write you a simple for loop? Not that you *should go down this road, but just an option, as I'm not used to the kind of  code you have

```
int count = 0;
double sum = 0.0;
foreach(DataRow row in dTable.Rows){
  if(row[col] != DBNull.Value)
  {
    sum += row[col];  //assuming its type double, or convert it if not
    count++;
  }
}
double avg = sum/count;
```

Comment: @bemused Yes! Thank you. I forgot about that

Comment: It might come down to this. This will definitely work. I just wanted something clever using the IEnumberable kind of stuff. (Trying to learn new stuff)

Comment: Seems like Isaac did it for me. If you wanted to include the null values into the avg, you would keep `count++` outside the `if` statement, which is what I assumed

Answer (score 0):

If the value is missing from the table can you not treat it as 0?  If so then you can simply return 0 in that case.

But if empty value means that it shouldn't even be included in the average... then you need to calculate the average yourself, similar to the post above.

Not sure if I understand the question correctly... hope it helps.