# Averaging DataTable Columns - Specified Cast is Invalid

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, average

I am attempting to average the values in every column after the fifth column in a datatable using this strategy

```
List<double> mylist = new List<double>();
        for (int col = 5; col < GridData.Columns.Count; col++)
        {
            double avg = GridData.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(x => x[GridData.Columns[col]] != DBNull.Value)
             .Average(x => x.Field<double>(GridData.Columns[col]));
            mylist.Add(avg);
        }
```

which has been modified from what I found at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864261/conditionally-average-a-column-of-data-in-a-datatable).

Every time I run this, it gives me a "specified cast is invalid" error on the line - `.Average(x => x.Field<double>(GridData.Columns[col]));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be just parsing the string that is in the DataTable field but you must be sure that you can parse the value. Check this:

```
List<double> mylist = new List<double>();
for (int col = 5; col < GridData.Columns.Count; col++)
{
       double avg = GridData.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(x => x[col] != DBNull.Value)
            .Average(x => double.Parse(x[col].ToString()));
                mylist.Add(avg);
}
```

Or even better with using `TryParse`

```
List<double> mylist = new List<double>();
for (int col = 0; col < GridData.Columns.Count; col++)
{
       double a;
       double avg = GridData.AsEnumerable()
             .Where(x => x[col] != DBNull.Value)
             .Average(x => double.TryParse(x[col].ToString(), out a) ? a:0.0);
                   mylist.Add(avg);
}
```

And the third one, safest but with redundant parsing:

```
for (int col = 0; col < GridData.Columns.Count; col++)
            {
                double a;
                double avg = GridData.AsEnumerable()
                    .Where(x => x[col] != DBNull.Value && double.TryParse(x[col].ToString(), out a))
                    .Average(x => double.Parse(x[col].ToString()));
                mylist.Add(avg);
            }
```

Comment: The first solution you provided allowed the code to run and the list to fill with averages.  However, all of the averages appear incorrect, so Im unsure if this solved whatever my root problem was.  If all the values in the columns for which Im calculating are floats, why is it complaining about a string to begin with?

Comment: I didn't understand you question exactly, I tried the code and it works for some example DataTable. I would suggest the third solution. I find that the best although you will parse each value twice but the values that are not double won't addup as 0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, the error:

```
System.Data.Datarow does not contain a defintion for Field
```

suggests that the generic extension method [`Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383067.aspx):

```
public static T Field<T>(this DataRow row, DataColumn column)
```

is not found.  Have you referenced the assembly with extension methods for `DataRow`?

```
System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
```

And you should probably add a `using` for it:

```
using System.Data.DataSetExtensions;
```

Comment: When I try `.Average(x => x.Field<double>(Convert.ToDouble(GridData.Columns[col])));` it will not compile and I get the errors "System.Data.Datarow does not contain a defintion for Field" and "cannot convert from double to string."  When I try `.Average(x => x.Field<double>((double)GridData.Columns[col]));` it will not compile either and I get the same two errors as well as "cannot convert "System.Data.DataColumn to double" and "cannot convert from double to string"

Comment: Yes. I just checked and it is referenced.  However, it does not appear as an option when trying to list it with a using.